# Android: Reduce the width of a cell in PdfPTable

Tags: android, itext, pdfptable

I have a `PdfPTable` for the footer of my PDF. The footer should contain three sentences one below the other. Also a Barcode Image should be there below this footer. In my current implementation, I am doing it in the following way:

```
PdfPTable FooterNote = new PdfPTable(1);
FooterNote.setTotalWidth(222f);
PdfPCell note1 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("MY First Text Here",
                font1));
PdfPCell note2 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(
                "My Second Text Here.", font1));
PdfPCell note3 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(
                "My Third Text here", font1));
note1.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
note2.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
note3.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
note3.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
note1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
note2.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
FooterNote.setWidthPercentage(100f);
FooterNote.addCell(note1);
FooterNote.addCell(note2);
FooterNote.addCell(note3);
FooterNote.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
FooterNote.setKeepTogether(true);

PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
Barcode128 code128 = new Barcode128();
code128.setCodeType(Barcode.CODE128);
String barcodeNumber = "MY BARCODE NUMBER";
code128.setCode(barcodeNumber);
Image barcodeImage = code128.createImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null);
barcodeImage.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
code128.setBarHeight(20f);
code128.setBaseline(20f);
code128.setX(10.0f);
code128.setGuardBars(false);
document.add(FooterNote);
document.add(barcodeImage);
```

[image: My Current Implementation]

Now as per the new requirement, The Barcode and the footer should not get split into two different page. To acheive that I added barcode to my Footer Table instead of adding it directly to my `Document` variable. Below is the code for that:

```
PdfPTable FooterNote = new PdfPTable(1);
FooterNote.setTotalWidth(222f);
PdfPCell note1 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("My First Text Here",
                font1));
PdfPCell note2 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(
                "My Second Text Here.", font1));
PdfPCell note3 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(
                "My Third Text Here.", font1));
note1.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
note2.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
note3.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
note3.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
note1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
note2.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
FooterNote.setWidthPercentage(100f);
FooterNote.addCell(note1);
FooterNote.addCell(note2);
FooterNote.addCell(note3);
FooterNote.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
FooterNote.setKeepTogether(true);

PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
Barcode128 code128 = new Barcode128();
code128.setCodeType(Barcode.CODE128);
String barcodeNumber = "MY BARCODE NUMBER";
code128.setCode(barcodeNumber);
Image barcodeImage = code128.createImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null);
barcodeImage.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
code128.setBarHeight(20f);
code128.setBaseline(20f);
code128.setX(10.0f);
code128.setGuardBars(false);
//FooterNote.addCell(barcodeImage);
//PdfPTable barcodeTable = new PdfPTable(1);
//barcodeTable.setTotalWidth(Utilities.millimetersToPoints(45));
//barcodeTable.setWidthPercentage(60f);
//barcodeTable.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
PdfPCell barcodeCell=new PdfPCell();
//barcodeCell.setImage(barcodeImage);
barcodeCell.addElement(barcodeImage);
barcodeCell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
barcodeCell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
//barcodeTable.addCell(barcodeCell);
FooterNote.addCell(barcodeCell);
//FooterNote.addCell(barcodeTable);
document.add(FooterNote);
```

I have tried 3 variation in the above code

1. Adding Image directly to the footer table.
2. Adding Image to a PDfPCell and then adding it to footer table.
3. Adding Image to a PDFPTable and then adding it to footer table.

But, In all the above 3 cases, I am getting unexpected result where my Barcode is getting streched more than the width I require it to be. See the below Image.
[image: PDF after my changes]

It will be great if someone can help me out on How I can change my last cell width to match my original Implementation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-two-images-one-cell

Comment: @SamuelHuylebroeck, Thanks! It worked.